# .on click event not firing inside Gmaps Infowindow with Fusion Tables info

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Using Fusion Tables and GMaps(v3) with Jquery(v1.7.1).

Gmaps displays a layer using Fusion Tables data.  The InfoWindow is populated using Fusion Tables information (configured in the Google Docs -> Fusion Table -> Configure Info Window interface).

At the bottom of the custom HTML of the FT Info Window is a link that reads:

```
<div><a class="detail" href=#><b>Click to see more detail</b></a>
</div>
```

I have JQuery testing to see if it is clicked and then executing code.

```
$('.detail').on('click', function(){
    console.log('Click worked');
});
```

The JQuery code is inside the initialize function that runs on body "onload".
I was using the .live jquery handler but that has been deprecated and was giving me problems anyways.  The .on handler isn't firing though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is `console.log` is displaying or not??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you're currently using `on`, only anchors that exist when the page is rendered will be wired up with this click handler; dynamically added anchors will not be picked up like they were with `live`.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.detail', function(){
    console.log('Click worked');
});
```

Now all clicks that happen anywhere in the document will be observed, and any coming from an element with the class `detail` will cause the function to fire.

But this is wasteful.  Hopefully there's some sort of container that you know will always contain these anchors.  If there is, you could do:

```
$("#someDivId").on('click', '.detail', function(){
    console.log('Click worked');
});
```

Now only clicks happening from inside the element with the id `someDivId` will be observed.

Comment: Since the container is a div in the Google infowindow, it doesn't have a unique ID (as far as I can tell), it is a class.  I tried $('.detail').on('click', function() { ... } but that didn't work.

Comment: @Josh - I'm not an expert on Google windows or else I'd try to help.  Sorry.  I'm sure you can post a new question and there'll likely be some people with more experience in this area that can help you

Comment: You could use the outer div which contains Google Maps, eg `<div id="#map">`. This way all links in/on the map will work, and it won't be as wasteful as observing your entire site.